# How to enlarge the Netbeans IDE icon, menu and toolbar fonts?

Tags: java, netbeans

As you can see in the image below, the icons, menus and toolbar of NetBeans are too small in my system.

How can I make the Netbeans IDE icon, menu and toolbar fonts larger?

This is the image of my NetBeans environment:

[image: IDE screen shot]

Comment: Verify that the menu option **View > Toolbars > Small Toolbar Icons** is not selected. But even if it is, deselecting it may not even fix your toolbar issue satisfactorily because the change in icon size is not significant.

Answer (score 0):

Try performing a

> ctrl+Up button

or a

> ctrl+Shift+(+ symbol)

for zooming in and

> ctrl+Down button

or a

> ctrl+Shift+(-symbol)

for zooming out

If none of these work, right-click and choose for font enlargement  or minimization. (This one might only work for font)

Comment: Re _"If none of these work..."_, it is better to verify that your suggestions actually work in your environment before posting an answer. None of them resolve any of the issues raised in the question.

Comment: I did this but unfortunately it still did not work.

Comment: I guess then you can try using this:  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GH-nwmzVlUI)